# Gitorious Git-daemon Ruby Gem Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, ruby-enterprise-edition

I'm installing gitorious on my webserver. Everything works fine except git-deamon, I get the following error when I run it

```
/etc/init.d/git-daemon start
Starting git-daemon: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `setup': 
You have already activated daemons 1.1.4, but your Gemfile requires daemons 1.1.0.
Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/../config/preinitializer.rb:16
    from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
    from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
    from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
    from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/boot.rb:123
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /var/www/gitorious/script/../config/environment.rb:11
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /var/www/gitorious/script/git-daemon:11

 failure
```

I have installed enterprise ruby 1.8.7 and ruby gems 1.4.2. I'm running ubuntu 11.04.

How could i solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way (but not very future-proof):

```
gem uninstall daemons
cd /var/www/gitorious
bundle install
```

The hard way: modify `/etc/init.d/git-daemon` so that it runs `cd /var/www/gitorious && bundle exec /var/www/gitorious/script/git-daemon start`

Comment: Actually, when using the most recent gems and rubygems using bundle all the way is the only way to have it work. So modifying the script the hard way is working. Thanks a lot !